# Check if MyString[1] is an alphabetical character?

Tags: string, delphi, char, character

I have a string, lets call it `MyStr`. I am trying to get rid of every non-alphabetical character in the string. Like, in IM's like MSN and Skype, people put their display names like **[-Bobby-]**. I would like to remove everything in that string that is not an alphabetical character, so all I am left with, is the "name".

How can I do that in Delphi? I was thinking about creating a `TStringlist` and store each valid character in there, and then use `IndexOf` to check if the char is valid, but I was hoping for an easier way.

Comment: `TStringList` sounds **very** inefficient...

Comment: @Jeff - do you need to handle just Ansi strings (English characters) or Unicode characters?

Comment: @Ken - I need characters like "æ ø å", too.

Comment: @Jeff You don't need to start all your questions with "Hello SO" and you don't need to sign off since we can see your name and mug shot under the Q.  Also, use two newlines to create paragraphs.  I've edited your question to that effect. +1 anyway, good Q.

Comment: @David - just being polite :P

Comment: @Jeff I know, it's appreciated!

Comment: +1 finally someone who realizes the Alphabet does not only consist of lowercase/uppercase A..Z!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The simplest approach is

```
function GetAlphaSubstr(const Str: string): string;
const
  ALPHA_CHARS = ['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
var
  ActualLength: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, length(Str));
  ActualLength := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if Str[i] in ALPHA_CHARS then
    begin
      inc(ActualLength);
      result[ActualLength] := Str[i];
    end;
  SetLength(Result, ActualLength);
end;
```

but this will only consider English letters as "alphabetical characters". It will not even consider the extremely important Swedish letters Å, Ä, and Ö as "alphabetical characters"!

Slightly more sophisticated is

```
function GetAlphaSubstr2(const Str: string): string;
var
  ActualLength: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, length(Str));
  ActualLength := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if Character.IsLetter(Str[i]) then
    begin
      inc(ActualLength);
      result[ActualLength] := Str[i];
    end;
  SetLength(Result, ActualLength);
end;
```

Comment: @Andreas - +1! Is it possible to include the Æ Ø Å and those too? Thanks!

Comment: In the first approach, you can just add them in the set (`'Æ', 'Ø', 'Å', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'å', 'ä', 'ö'`). The latter approach, using `IsLetter`, will automatically include all letters from all languages.

Comment: @Jeff GetAlphaSubstr2 does just that

Comment: +1 Perfect. I would have written code identical to `GetAlphaSubstr2`.

Comment: @David - Ah, nice! Will do that now! :) Gotta modify it so it will trash everything after the First name has been extracted.

Comment: Accepted - I used the Character.IsLetter function, and made my function do what I needed.

Comment: @Jeff: To modify it that way you can just add `else if Str[i] = #32 then break;`. Or maybe you wish to count space as a letter? That is very easily achieved in the first approach, and also in the latter. I leave the details as an exercise for you (it's very easy!).

Comment: +1 for using  `IsLetter`  which checks the Unicode definition for being a letter or not http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Character.TCharacter.IsLetter

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers the correct link now is: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Character.TCharacter.IsLetter

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis oh nice, they broke the redirect chain when resurrecting their documentation (see the redirect chain at https://wheregoes.com/trace/20223758375/). Originally my link would always redirect to the most current product version as that was designed into the help-system.
Currently it does: https://wheregoes.com/trace/20223758419/
Hopefully http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Character.TCharacter.IsLetter will be pointing to the most recent documentation for a while now.

Answer (score 6):

try this code to check if a char is a alphabetical character.

```
  MyStr:='[-Bobby-]';
  //is an alphabetical character ?
  if MyStr[1] in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z'] then
```

to remove from a string all the non alphabetical characters (English characters) you can use something like this.

```
NewStr:='';
for i := 1 to Length(MyStr) do
 if MyStr[i] in ['a'..'z','A'..'Z'] then
   NewStr:=NewStr+MyStr[i];
```

now the `NewStr` variable only contains alphabetical characters.

in newer versions of delphi you can use the [`Character.IsLetter`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.Character.TCharacter.IsLetter) function.

Comment: What about a locale dependent version covering the rest of the alphabetic characters outside the A..Z range?

Comment: @jeroen, the answer states `...to remove from a string all the non alphabetical characters (English characters)` to cover  the rest of the alphabetic characters the OP can use the `Character.IsLetter` function or just expand the set with the additional chars like andreas explain in the commnents.

Comment: changed the broken link, the old was pointing to VCL's Character.IsLetter, but seems now one should go to System.Character.TCharacter.IsLetter

Answer (score 1):

I have a whole suite of optimised string routines to do this stuff, which work with both Unicode and non-Unicode Delphi. The two most relevant ones are:

```
function CsiRemoveArgs(const pInStr: string; const pArgs: string;
                       pRestrictToArgs: Boolean = False): string;
function CsiRemoveArgs(const pInStr: string; pArgs: TSysCharSet;
                       pRestrictToArgs: Boolean = False): string;
```

You can download them [here](http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_utilities.htm).

Comment: +1 for routines that allow for covering the rest of the alphabetic characters outside the A..Z range.

Comment: @Misha has this link gone rogue? shows fraudulent offer to me

Answer (score 0):

Perfect Solution:

```
Result := TRegEx.Replace('Input12231213','[^a-zA-Z]+','');  // Result = 'Input'
```

Works in Delphi XE

http://regexpstudio.com

Comment: Even in America, people should be less naïve than this.