# How to delete chars from string until first char is a letter?

Tags: string, delphi, pascal

I have a program which works with strings (Pascal). After reading a string if the first char is not a letter then I need to delete all first characters until the first is a letter. I have tried to write it several times, but always it deletes all string or nothing.

If program reads "123%^&abc" then result should be "abc"
In ASCII table letters are from 65..90 and from 97..122

This is how far I am:

```
variables    a: set of 65..90;
             b: set of 97..122;
-------------------
  bool:=false;
  While (bool=false) do
  begin
    Writeln(s[1]);
    If (Ord(s[1]) in a) or (Ord(s[1]) in b) then
    begin
    bool:=true;
    end else
    delete(s,1,1);
  end;
```

I don't understand why it does not work?
Can you help me with this little procedure? Thank you.

Comment: It's been a while since I haven't done some Pascal, but your program seems fine to me, can you paste the output for a given string ? Or eventually errors

Comment: And, as always, I add the delphi tag so that your question will get some real attention!

Comment: I see no mistake in that program. I don't like its style, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work as intended.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: As I remark in the end of my answer, there are a couple of mistakes: the OP code doesn't handle "pathological" inputs very well.

Comment: a and b are uninitialized variables. Just because they are defined as sets which can contain the values 65 to 90 and 97 to 122 does not mean that all these bits are actually set.

Comment: @Thorsten: Indeed, one must write `const a = [65..90]; b = [97..122]`. I assume that the OP did that, but you might be right. Maybe the OP wrote `var a: set of 65..90; b: set of 97..122`, which declares `a` and `b` as variables that, by later assignment, can store *any* sets of integers in the specified ranges. The lesson to the OP might be to include the *exact* code that doesn't work in the question, and not pseudocode! (`65..90` is a so-called "subrange type"; hence `set of 65..90` is like `set of byte` but more picky about the elements.)

Comment: `while (bool=false) do` ... OMG. First, why on earth do you name the variable `bool`, instead of (for example) `completed`? Bool could be confused with a type name, so it's a bad name for anything else. Next, why don't you just write `while not completed do`? Would be much more readable and transport your intention much better.

Comment: Thank You, @JensG ! I thought about that for almost 3 years. Now it makes sense :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do

```
function RemoveNonAlphaASCIIFromStart(const Str: AnsiString): AnsiString;
const
  ALPHA = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];
var
  i: Integer;
  firstIndex: integer;
begin
  result := '';
  firstIndex := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if Str[i] in ALPHA then
    begin
      firstIndex := i;
      break;
    end;
  if firstIndex > 0 then
    result := Copy(Str, firstIndex, length(Str));
end;
```

or, as a procedure

```
procedure RemoveNonAlphaASCIIFromStart(var Str: AnsiString);
const
  ALPHA = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];
var
  i: Integer;
  firstIndex: integer;
begin
  firstIndex := 0;
  for i := 1 to length(Str) do
    if Str[i] in ALPHA then
    begin
      firstIndex := i;
      break;
    end;
  if firstIndex > 0 then
    Delete(Str, 1, firstIndex - 1)
  else
    Str := '';
end;
```

For more sophisticated methods, that also work with Unicode Delphi, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171784/check-if-mystring1-is-an-alphabetical-character). [This removes all non-alpha chars from the string.]

So, why doesn't your algorithm work? Well, it should work, and it works for me. But notice that it can be written in the slightly more elegant form

```
const
  ALPHA = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];

while true do
  if (length(s) = 0) or (s[1] in ALPHA) then
    break
  else
    delete(s, 1, 1);
```

One problem, however, with the OP's original code is that it will fail if `s` is the empty string. Indeed, then `s[1]` doesn't exist. It won't work either if `s` consists entirely of non-alpha characters (e.g. `'!"#¤%`).

Comment: Much better style than the OP, but just like you I see no mistake in the original code.

Comment: Notice that I rely on boolean short-circuit evaluation (BSCE) in the `if` statement in the last block of code. I am not sure if plain Pascal employs BSCE.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: does it matter? So you get 99 rep instead of 100... seems that most people like your work.

Comment: @moz: You are right. It is not the rep points though -- I just think it feels odd when someone apparently downvotes every answer I make. I think too much...

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand-Do you know if deleting characters (Delete) is faster than copying part of the string (Copy)?

Answer (score 2):

Allthough the previous solutions do work, they are highly ineffitient. Because of 2 reasons:
1. Searching in a set is time consuming
2. Deleting every time a character out of a string is even more ineffitient, as the string (object) has to remove the character internally and adjust its array, etc.

Ideally you cast your string into PChar and work with that, while checking the char-range "manually". We'll let the search run until we find the first letter and only then we call the DeleteString method. Here's a demo on my approach:

```
procedure Frapp;
var
  TheString: string;
  pcStr: PChar;
  StrLen, I: Integer;
begin
  TheString := '123%^&abc';
  StrLen := Length(TheString);
  pcStr := PChar(TheString);

  for I := 0 to StrLen - 1 do
  begin
    if ((pcStr^ >= #65) and (pcStr <= #90)) or ((pcStr >= #97) and (pcStr <= #122)) then
    begin
      Delete(TheString, 1, I);
      Break;
    end;
    Inc(pcStr);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Notice that neither of my two algorithms suffer from repeated `Delete` calls (which are indeed very inefficient). Anyhow, your code above doesn't work...

Comment: My apologies. You don't call Delete too often. But why do you say my code wouldn't work?

Comment: I tried it. It produces `^&abc`, and not the expected `abc`. UPDATE: But I was in such a hurry then (to catch the bus)! Indeed, it doesn't work in *Delphi 2009* and later (which are *Unicode*)! But it *does* work with pure ANSI strings! My apologies!