# Access Violation 00000000 when using Delete();

Tags: string, delphi, char, access-violation

I am trying to delete every character from the beginning of my string, that is not an Alpha-character.

**However**, when there are only non-alpha characters (like "!!" or "?!?") in the string, it spits out an Access Violation!

Here is my code:

```
  // The Log(); is a routine that adds stuff to my log memo.
  Log('Begin Parse');
  while not IsLetter(ParsedName[1]) do
   begin
     Log('Checking Length - Length is '+IntToStr(Length(ParsedName))+' ...');
     if Length(ParsedName) <> 0 then
     Begin
     Log('Deleting Char ...');
     Delete(ParsedName,1,1);
     Log('Deleted Char ...');
     End;
     Log('Checking Length - Length is now '+IntToStr(Length(ParsedName))+' ...');
   end;
   // It never reaches this point!
   Log('End Parse');
```

This is what my log produces:

```
21:51:19: Checking Length - Length is 2 ...
21:51:19: Deleting Char ...
21:51:19: Deleted Char ...
21:51:19: Checking Length - Length is now 1 ...
21:51:19: Checking Length - Length is 1 ...
21:51:19: Deleting Char ...
21:51:19: Deleted Char ...
21:51:19: Checking Length - Length is now 0 ...
21:51:19: Access violation at address 007A1C09 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000000
```

As you see, it happens right after all the chars have been deleted. I assume the problem lies that somehow, I am trying to access something that is not there, but **how** I am doing that, I cannot see.

EDIT: Yes, I know it's a **stupid** question and all that stuff - I just oversaw something. Don't tell me that doesen't ever happen to you ;)

Comment: @Jeff, it's great when you add logging for troubleshooting. However, if you're going to add logging code, you should learn to actually read the log entries. The answer to your problem is obvious from the next to last line of your log: "21:51:19: Checking Length - **Length is now 0** ...". Obviously, if length is now 0, accessing ParsedName[1] will fail, since there's no ParsedName[] any longer.

Comment: The access violation never would have happened if you had **turned on range checking**. Go to your compiler options and turn it on right now. Then, never turn it off. The additional time it takes your program to run is negligible compared the the amount of time it saves you troubleshooting.

Comment: Further to Ken's comment, reading the log more closely also would have shown you that  you had no reason to conclude that Delete was the culprit since your program was able to log an additional two messages after calling it. The problem was somewhere between the "Length is now" message and either the "Length is" or the "End Parse" messages. The only thing between those is IsLetter, so set a breakpoint there and see whether you can figure out why it might crash on the particular value of ParsedName that you had on that iteration.

Comment: Logging is a good thing. By using logging, you can often pinpoint hard-to-find bugs in long pieces of code. But this piece isn't long! IMHO it looks simply silly with all this logging. Instead, you should sit down and *think* about the piece of code. (In advanced books, it isn't uncommon that algorithms are presented almost like mathematical theorems, in the sense that they are followed by strict *proofs* of their validity.)

Comment: It seems you guys don't welcome newbie questions. I will remember that for the next time..

Comment: +1 Underrated, dunno why the -1 votes, looks like a valid question. Even if the bug is silly/monday morning type, the answer got +9, so obviously it is a good question, if the answer is **that** good. right?

Comment: +1 keep asking someone will learn something from your questions, welcome

Comment: This got downvoted because it shouldn't have been asked in the first place; Simple F8 (step over) debugging would have correctly identified the problem in half the time it took to copy-paste the code to SO. The answer being upvoted allot has nothing to do with the quality of the question. In fact the obvious answer to very simple questions always gather lots of upvotes on SO (says something about the community, not about the quality of the question or answer). @Najem, what will someone learn from this question? That an **empty** string doesn't contain an first character?

Comment: @Cosmin I am sure the OP learned something that doing a basic debugging will solve problems and save time. other hand of my upvote is the spirit of delphi community to welcome everyone. maybe we can make an agreement and add a new tag like DelphiNewbi to SO then the community active members can change the Delphi tag depending on quality of the question.

Comment: @Najem, if you're interested in what is and isn't welcomed at SO, feel free to roam around [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) because that's where the inner workings of the site and it's community are discussed. You'll find lots of discussions about the diminishing quality of questions. Feel free to ask a question over there, why this question got downvoted and if the downvotes were merited. Make sure you word your question in a constructive manner.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with `Delete`. Delete works even if you tell it to delete characters that do not exist.

The line

```
while not IsLetter(ParsedName[1]) do
```

tries to access `ParsedName[1]`, so this character has better to exist. Your code isn't particularly beautiful, but a simple workaround is

```
while (length(ParsedName) > 0) and not IsLetter(ParsedName[1]) do
```

You can do just

```
while (length(ParsedName) > 0) and not IsLetter(ParsedName[1]) do
  Delete(ParsedName, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Just what I needed - thanks! `Your code isn'r particularly beautiful`  Just out of interest, how would you do it?

Comment: Also, reason I added Delete, was because I assumed that was where it all screwed up.

Comment: Look at the code for Trim in SysUtils, and do the same with IsLetter(..) - much quicker too.

Comment: @Edelcom: I know. In fact, I usually complain when people use `Delete` in loops. But in this case I am pretty sure that the OP care more about learning the basics of algorithms than about performance. I also don't think that the code will be used for very large strings.

Comment: @Edelcom: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171784/check-if-mystring1-is-an-alphabetical-character for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to also add in a check that the length of the string is > 0 in the While test.

You are checking to see if it is numeric before your if statement to check the length of the string. Alternately you could move your check of the string length to After where you remove the character. However ya want to do it :)

Comment: I believe I already did that - `if Length(ParsedName) <> 0 then`

Comment: Yeah I just updated the answer to specify where it was needed. Sorry about that :)

Comment: So did I not do it right? Would you mind editing my code to reflect your changes? Thanks! :)