# write a number into a file

Tags: pascal

I made a program to put a number in a file. But the file don't show that number(i'mean my code is working but when open the file i created he doesn't show the number.

Here is the code:

```
Program firstfich;
Uses Wincrt; 

Type fich = file Of Integer; 
Var f: fich; 
x: Integer; {start } 
Begin 
  Assign(f,'C:\a progremming works bac\first bac programe\kill.dat');   
  Rewrite(f); 
  x := 47; 
  Write(f,x); 
  Close(f); 
End.
```

Comment: It's not going to display 47, because that's a string of two characters, not the integer number 47. You're not writing a string of two characters that contain '4' and '7'. The question is what do you get when you read it back in to an integer variable?

Comment: IOW, if you open the file in a hex editor what you should see is 0x2F000000 or 0x0000002F depending on the endianness. 2F is hexadecimal for decimal 47.

Comment: You did provide the program code (which is fine) but we can only make assumption on your problem. What do you get, what did you expect? Do you want to read the number back in another program, or do you expect the number to be readable when opening the file with a text editor? BTW, stay concise in the title of a question, you can put the whole description in the body of the question. Like when you send an email.

Comment: If you want to see "47" when you open the file in a text editor, you shouldn't create a file containing the byte 47 (which is the ASCII code for the solidus character "/"). Instead, you should create a file containing the bytes 52 and 55, which are the ASCII codes for the characters "4" and "7", respectively. You should read about how text files are represented in computer memory. See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding

Comment: @Seki yes  i expect the number to be readable when opening the file with a text edito

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand can you write a code of what about you talking about

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see "47" when you open the file **in a text editor**, you should *not* create a file containing the byte 47 (which is the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) code for the solidus character "/").

Instead, you should create a file containing the bytes 52 and 55, which are the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) codes for the characters "4" and "7", respectively.

You should read about how text files are represented in computer memory. See, e.g., [the Wikipedia article on character encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

Now, to create a file containing the bytes 52 and 55, you just write the *string* "47" to the file (all code is in Delphi, a modern Pascal implementation -- if you are using some other Pascal implementation, you might need to modify the code slightly):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  f: text;

begin
  try
    try
      AssignFile(f, 'D:\number.txt');
      Rewrite(f);
      Write(f, '47');
      CloseFile(f);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Writeln('Done.');
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

This will create a file that contains two bytes: 52 and 55. A text editor will display the characters "4" and "7" (assuming ASCII).

On the contrary, if you would create a file that contains only the byte 47, a text editor would display the solidus character ("/", assuming ASCII).

If you want to see the actual bytes in a file, you shouldn't open it in a text editor, but in a hex editor. I encourage you to download a hex editor and play around with these concepts to learn more about them.

**Update, in response to comment:** If you insist on writing bytes manually, using old Pascal I/O, the following works in Delphi:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

var
  b: Byte;
  f: file;

begin
  try
    try
      AssignFile(f, 'C:\Users\Andreas Rejbrand\Desktop\number.txt');
      Rewrite(f, 1);
      b := 52; // Or, better: Ord('4')
      BlockWrite(f, b, 1);
      b := 55; // Or, better: Ord('7')
      BlockWrite(f, b, 1);
      CloseFile(f);
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Writeln('Done.');
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

Still, this is a horrible way of creating a text file containing the number "47"; it should only be considered for educational purposes. To see alternatives to old Pascal I/O, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298368/282848.

Comment: Program Project1;
Uses Wincrt;
Var
  f: Text;
Begin
  AssignFile(f, 'c:\number.txt');
  Rewrite(f);
  Write(f, '47');
  CloseFile(f);
  Writeln('Done.');
  Readln;
End.

Comment: but can we do that with type file (that what i want )

Comment: @Taher: Well, exactly how you should do it depends on what kind of Pascal you are using. Pascal I/O is ancient and shouldn't be used these days. Instead, modern Pascal implementations, like Delphi and FreePascal, have modern classes that should be used instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58298368/282848 for some examples.

Comment: ok thx man for help that was my first time in stackoverflow and it was amaizing i will ask many quastion when learning html ,javascript ,php , and java

Comment: @Taher: Glad I could help.

Comment: thx man relay thx man you help so much nice you relay good guy and that true i need that for educational purpose

Answer (score 0):

```
program numbertofile;
var
        f: TextFile;
        x: Integer;
begin
        assign(f, 'kill.dat');
        rewrite(f);
        x := 47;
        write(f, x);
        close(f);
end.
```

Comment: Can you add some description on how your code differ from the OP?

Comment: Is it really not visible? "f: TextFile;" vs "Type fich = file Of Integer;  Var f: fich;".

Comment: It could not be obvious to a beginner, which I guess the OP is. Accompanying a code sample with a comment in an answer is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just make your file a text file and your integer will be saved in the file the way you expect it to.   Just set your file to a text variable like this:

```
Var f: text; 
x: Integer; {start } 
Begin 
  Assign(f,'C:\a progremming works bac\first bac programe\kill.dat');   
  Rewrite(f); 
  x := 47; 
  Write(f,x); 
  Close(f); 
End.
```

note the write will not put a carriage return or linefeed after the line.  if you want numbers on different lines use writeln instead of write.

```
Writeln(f,x);
```