# Use array concatenation syntax for adding items instead of add them manually

Tags: delphi

I would like to use array concatenation syntax in "recently" Delphi versions (10.1+)

```
IntArr := IntArr + [2];
```

instead of

```
SetLength(IntArr, Length(IntArr) + 1);
IntArr[High(IntArr)] := 2;
```

The former is obviously more compact and I don't need to manage explicity the array length; I could even add several items at once:

```
IntArr := IntArr + [2, 5, 9];
```

**1) Is there any risk, const or caveat when the former syntax is used?**

**2) Does it work fine with any type (record, string, object, etc.)?**

**3) Is it the former slower than the latter?**

PD: I am using Delphi 10.1 (Berlin)

Comment: 1) If the code you write works, then there is no problem. 2) It should do, unless there are bugs in the RTL. Test it. 3) Time the two options in suitable real world settings. 4) Both variants are liable to lead to heap fragmentation when abused.

Comment: Building a dynamic array by adding a single item at a time is rather inefficient, and generally an anti-pattern. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756206/282848 for details. But for small arrays and non-time-critical parts of the code (that is, most parts), it is generally not a problem in practice. And in those cases, both your approaches are fine, but the concise version is much more readable.

Comment: By the way, wasn't this syntax introduced in XE7?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, language feature introduced in XE7, bugs still being removed from the implementation however