# Error in delphi while working with functions and arrays

Tags: arrays, image, function, delphi

[image]

This error is occurring when I'm filling an array through a function. The function fills an array with all the details stored in a textfile. The code works in filling the array, but when I tried using it in a function it doesn't work.

```pascal
type
  DynamicArray = array of string; 

Function fillarr(ArrParm: DynamicArray; FileName: String): DynamicArray;
Var
  tf: TextFile;
  sWord: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  SetLength(ArrParm, 1);
  AssignFile(tf, FileName);
  Reset(tf);
  while not eof(tf) do
  begin
    Readln(tf, sWord);
    ArrParm[i] := sWord;
    Inc(i);
    SetLength(ArrParm, i + 1);
  end;
  SetLength(ArrParm, i - 1);
  Result := ArrParm;
end;

procedure TForm4.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
Var
  arrPictures: DynamicArray;
begin
  FillArr(arrPictures, 'NameOfTheTextFile.txt');
  ShowMessage(arrPictures[1]); // Error occurs here
```

Comment: I suggest using a `TStringList` instead of messing up with dynamic arrays...

Comment: @Olivier I'm trying to learn how to use dynamic arrays, thats the reason for me using them.

Comment: Well the code has a wrong structure. If the file is empty, you call `SetLength(ArrParm, -1);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must understand that [dynamic arrays](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Arrays) are reference types, but the references are passed by value.

In `TForm4.FormShow`, you have a dynamic array variable `arrPictures`. Even though this is a *local* variable, it is initialized because it is a dynamic array, which is a managed type. Specifically, it is `nil` ([a zero-length dynamic array](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Internal_Data_Formats_(Delphi)#Dynamic_Array_Types)) at the beginning. Hence, the second element `arrPictures[1]` does not exist at the beginning of this method.

You attempt to populate the array with your call to `FillArr`. However, when you pass `arrPictures` to this method, the reference is passed by value, so `FillArr` obtains a *copy* of the pointer to the dynamic array heap object.

Now, the [`SetLength`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetLength) procedure reallocates the dynamic array heap object, so the pointer to it has to change. In other words, the value of the `ArrParm` variable changes, to point to *a new* dynamic array heap object. The initial one, which `TForm4.FormShow` is aware of, is left unchanged. (But in this case it didn't exist at all, because the array was `nil`, of zero length.)

Hence, when `fillarr` returns, `arrPictures` is still `nil`, and `arrPictures[1]` still doesn't exist. So you get an AV trying to read it.

The solution is to make the array parameter a `var` parameter, so the dynamic array variable is passed by reference. This way, when `FillArr` changes the value of the pointer, this change will be visible to the variable in `TForm4.FormShow`:

```
function fillarr(var ArrParm: DynamicArray; FileName: string): DynamicArray;
```

(`fillarr` is a function, and it actually *returns* the new array. But when you call this function in `TForm4.FormShow`, you discard the result value, so you gain nothing by it being a function. But this means that a different solution would be not to discard the result value. But then you can remove the parameter altogether. You don't need or want *two* ways for the routine to return the same value. *Either* let it be a procedure with a `var` or `out` parameter, *or* let it be a function with no parameters.)

---

In addition to this problem, there are other issues with the code. For instance, try to think about how you read the file. Can you do this with fewer `SetLength` calls?

(But in a real application, one should not use legacy Pascal I/O at all, and one should ["never"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756206/282848) increase the size of a dynamic array or string one element at a time.)

Comment: When you receive an answer which answers your question, it is a courtesy not only to the person who answered but also to future readers, to "accept" the answer by clickinfg the green "tick" icon next to its top left hand corner.  Andreas's answers are usually very thorough and well-informed so it would be good if you considered accepting this one.  Accepting an answer tells future readers that it answered your q.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand why is it a bad thing to use many. SetLength in a code?

Comment: @Umsugi: Suppose you create a 1000-element array `X` by doing `SetLength(X, Length(X) + 1); X[High(X)] := f(i)` 1000 times. Every time you call `SetLength`, the run-time library will make a new heap allocation. For instance, when the length is `562`and you call `SetLength(X, Length(X) + 1)` the following happens: (1) The system will give you a new area of memory for your new (longer) array. (2) The entire old array with its 562 elements is copied to the new location. If the array is an array of doubles, say (8 bytes per value), this will copy 8*562 = 4496 bytes. (3) The memory location of ...

Comment: (cont.) old array is released (marked as available for other use). After that, the 563rd element is written. Then, when it is time for the 564th element, the process repeats itself: you allocate a new area in memory, copy all 563 existing elements to the new area, mark the "old" area as free, and fill in the 564th element. This is *extremely* slow compared to allocating a 1000-element long array in the first place and filling its elements one by one, in that array.