# Adding Append method to the generic TArray type

Tags: arrays, delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to add an `Append` method to the `System.Generics.Collections.TArray` type.

```
unit uMyArray;

interface

uses
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TArray = class(System.Generics.Collections.TArray)
  public
    class procedure Append<T>(var AValues: array of T; const AItem: T); static;
  end;

implementation

class procedure TArray.Append<T>(var AValues: array of T; const AItem: T);
begin
  SetLength(AValues, Length(AValues) + 1);
  AValues[Length(AValues) - 1] := AItem;
end;

end.
```

On compiling I get the following error on the `SetLength` line:

> [dcc32 Error] uMyArray.pas(18): E2008 Incompatible types

Comment: Why don't you use `TList`?

Comment: Bit of an antipattern, this increase the length of the array by one. Can result in fragmented address space.

Comment: You shouldn't append one element at a time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756206/282848

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot resize an open array parameter. You need to pass `TArray<T>`.

Change

```
class procedure Append<T>(var AValues: array of T; const AItem: T); static;
```

to

```
class procedure Append<T>(var AValues: TArray<T>; const AItem: T); static;
```