# Read integers from a string

Tags: algorithm, input, pascal

I'm learning algorithms and I'm trying to make an algorithm that extracts numbers lets say `n` in [1..100] from a string. Hopefully I get an easier algorithm.

I tried the following :

```
procedure ReadQuery(var t : tab); // t is an array of Integer.
var 
    x,v,e : Integer;
    inputs : String;
begin
    //readln(inputs);
    inputs:='1  2 3';
    j:= 1;
    // make sure that there is one space between two integers
    repeat
        x:= pos('  ', inputs); // position of the space
        delete(inputs, x, 1)
    until (x = 0);
    x:= pos(' ', inputs); // position of the space
    while x <> 0 do
    begin  
        x:= pos(' ', inputs); //(1) '1_2_3' (2) '2_3'
        val(copy(inputs, 1, x-1), v, e); // v = value | e = error pos
        t[j]:=v;    
        delete(inputs, 1, x); //(1) '2_3' (2) '3'
        j:=j+1; //(1) j = 2 (2) j = 3
        //writeln(v);   
    end;
    //j:=j+1; // <--- The mistake were simply here.
    val(inputs, v, e);
    t[j]:=v;
    //writeln(v);   
end;
```

I get this result ( resolved ) :

```
1
2
0
3
```

expected :

```
1
2
3
```

PS : I'm not very advanced, so excuse me for reducing you to basics.
Thanks for everyone who is trying to share knowledge.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code is a little bit hard to understand, because we don't know what the variables `x`, `v`, `e` and `t` represent. Would you consider giving them self-explanatory names?

Comment: @Stef Hello, thanks for you reply i have put an explanation and also found the mistake while re-checking which is thanks to your kind reply. I'll keep this topic in case i can get a better idea as I'm doing some codeforces exercises and it's kinda hard to keep using this procedure each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is rather inefficient and it also doesn't work for strings containing numbers in general.

A standard and performant approach would be like this:

```pascal
type
  TIntArr = array of Integer;

function GetNumbers(const S: string): TIntArr;

const
  AllocStep = 1024;
  Digits = ['0'..'9'];

var
  i: Integer;
  InNumber: Boolean;
  NumStartPos: Integer;
  NumCount: Integer;

  procedure Add(Value: Integer);
  begin
    if NumCount = Length(Result) then
      SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + AllocStep);
    Result[NumCount] := Value;
    Inc(NumCount);
  end;

begin

  InNumber := False;
  NumCount := 0;
  for i := 1 to S.Length do
    if not InNumber then
    begin
      if S[i] in Digits then
      begin
        NumStartPos := i;
        InNumber := True;
      end;
    end
    else
    begin
      if not (S[i] in Digits) then
      begin
        Add(StrToInt(Copy(S, NumStartPos, i - NumStartPos)));
        InNumber := False;
      end;
    end;

  if InNumber then
    Add(StrToInt(Copy(S, NumStartPos)));

  SetLength(Result, NumCount);

end;
```

This code is intentionally written in a somewhat old-fashioned Pascal way. If you are using a modern version of Delphi, you wouldn't write it like this. (Instead, you'd use a `TList<Integer>` and make a few other adjustments.)

Try with the following inputs:

```
521 cats, 432 dogs, and 1487 rabbits
1 2 3 4 5000 star 6000
alpha1beta2gamma3delta
a1024b2048cdef32
a1b2c3
32h50s
5020
   012       123!    
horses
(empty string)
```

*Make sure you fully understand the algorithm! Run it on paper a few times, line by line.*

Comment: I would like to thank you for this great share and it's extremely helpful, I have carefully analyzed your code, and I have come up with some questions, that i wish you can explain, if your free time allows you.
What does the variable `Result` refer to, Why did you add a `value` with type integer to the `Result` which is seemed to be a string ( not declared ), and why did you prefer to create the `Add` procedure when there exists a predefined `Concat` procedure? 
The idea your algorithm is pretty clear, to run through the string until a number is found then it's supposed to be saved.

Comment: @CouldnoTB-Zone: Notice that almost the entire code block consists of the function `GetNumbers` which starts on the third non-blank line. This is a function that returns a `TIntArr`, a dynamic array of integers. In Pascal, `Result` is an implicit variable that contains the value the function returns, in this case the integer array. `Add` is a nested procedure within the `GetNumbers` function. Since this is a procedure and not a function, it has no `Result` variable of its own, so `Result` inside `Add` also refers to the result of `GetNumbers`.

Comment: In Pascal, building a dynamic array one item at a time is bad performance, because you need to make a heap (re)allocation every time, any copy the entire contents of the array to a new place in your computer's RAM. It is better to allocate one big array at the beginning, and the fill it. But this is problematic if you don't know the final length from the beginning. Hence, I allocate in chunks of size `AllocStep = 1024` elements at a time. So I initially allocate 1024 elements, and if I need more, I allocate 1024 more. This way I only need one reallocation (instead of 2000) if I end up with...

Comment: 2000 elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5756206/282848 for details. This is a rather advanced-level optimisation, so maybe I shouldn't have included it.